# Publishing to App Store using older Xcode version

Tags: ios, xcode

What happens to an app that's published to the **App Store** using an older version of Xcode?

Let's say we're on `Xcode 9` with comes with `iOS 11` then I'm publishing the app built targeting iOS 11.

Will people with `iOS 12.2`+ be able to download the app even-though `iOS 12.2`+ was not part of `Xcode 9`?

ps: I know I can have multiple version of Xcode on the same machine so this is not an answer.

Comment: You can't publish with an old versions of Xcode. Apple now requires you use Xcode 10.1 or later with a Base SDK of iOS 12.1 or later.

Comment: Think about this for the question you are actually asking - users with iOS 12.2 can download apps that haven't been updated in a couple of years.

Comment: XCode 10.1 is not the latest as XCode 10.2 is out. Does this mean XCode 10.1 cannot be used to publish?

Comment: I just said you can use Xcode 10.1 or later.

Comment: I know that apps that haven't been updated are still downloadable but this does not mean newly published apps are accepted.

Comment: Those are two independent things. The version of Xcode and the Base SDK that Apple requires for new apps has nothing to do with what a user can install on their device.

Comment: How can I tell in the future which version of XCode allows me to publish?

Comment: iTunes Connect shows you the requirement. But here's the easiest advice - always stay current. When a new version of Xcode comes out, upgrade. Always use the latest tools with Apple. You can still support older versions of iOS but Apple always wants you to support the latest versions.

Comment: And Apple sends an email to developers each time the requirement changes so that makes it easy to know.

Answer (score 1):

As per Apple:

> Starting March 27, 2019, all iOS apps submitted to the App Store will need to be built with the iOS 12.1 SDK or later, and support the all-screen design of iPhone XS Max or the 12.9-inch iPad Pro (3rd Generation). All watchOS apps will need to support watchOS 5 and Apple Watch Series 4.

While your app would run fine on any **iOS** version later than the targeted build version, Apple will reject your submission if not built with **Xcode 10.1** or later. That being said, you can set your target version to **iOS 10.0**, for example, without issue. You do not have to target **iOS 12.1**, you just need to build with the **12.1 SDK**.

See also: [App Store Connect Supported Xcode versions](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devb1c185036)